# Any possible way to make $wpdb->get_results() return anything else than array?

Tags: php, ajax, database, query, wpdb

So I'm using `$wpdb->get_results()` to query my database and then make AJAX call from JS file. The problem is that I need to get the value itself, like a string, instead of array, but as much as I know, get_results return only array. Is there any way around this to get string value from database? Or should I use something else than `get_results()`?

Comment: Why not use that array and get the string from it?

Comment: I converted it to JSON but still don't know how to access the string in the loop. I have an array of json objects here. Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

`$wpdb->get_results()` only returns arrays( associative or numeric) or an object.  It does not return a string value.

If you want a string value, you need to use [`$wpdb->get_var()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_var/) instead